# Prove that modified RBF function satisfies Mercer conditions.

Tags: covariance, positive-semidefinite, invariance, permutation-matrices, radial-basis-functions

Suppose that I have a modified [RBF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel) kernel function.

$k(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) = \exp{(-||\mathbf{x}-P\mathbf{y}||^2 })$

where $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$ represent $d$ dimensional inputs and $P$ is the permutation of the elements of the vector $\mathbf{y}$ such that $P\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{y}'$ minimizes $||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}'||^2$. We assume that inputs are permutation invariant, i.e. $\mathbf{y}$ and $P\mathbf{y}$ represent the same input.

This permutation can be found using the [Hungarian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) and the resulting permutation matrix $P$ will depend on both $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$. Can it be shown that this modified RBF function is still a kernel?

The problem can be reduced to proving that $k'(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{x}^TP\mathbf{y}$ is a valid kernel. If I try the Mercer conditions to prove positive semi-definiteness, the first part can be easily proven, that is

$k'(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=k'(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{x})$ is true since, no matter where $P$ operates the dot product will remain invariant.

However, for the second part, I don't think that I can find a map $\phi(\alpha)\;s.t.\; k'(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) = \left\langle\phi(\mathbf{x}),\phi(\mathbf{y})\right\rangle$. Is there any other way to prove that the modified RBF is indeed a kernel function?

In short, my input vectors $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$ are invariant under permutations of the input space and I want the kernel function to utilize that information while calculating the distance between two inputs so that the covariance matrix expresses this information.

Edit: minimize $||\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}'||^2 = ||\mathbf{x}||^2 +||\mathbf{y}'||^2 -2\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y}' \Rightarrow$ maximize $\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y}'$

If $y$ is a $d\times 1$ vector then there are $d!$ available permutations. If we denote each of them as $P_i$ then we create the function

$k(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) = \sum_1^{d!}\mathbf{x}^TP_i \mathbf{y} = \sum_1^{d!}\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{y}_i $, where $\mathbf{y}_i$ are the permutations of $\mathbf{y}$. Each $\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{y}_i $ should be a kernel and thus the sum of the kernels should be a kernel as well.

However, this is an intuition as we don't specifically want the sum of those functions but we wish to choose the maximum of those kernels.

Tl;dr: Is the function

$k(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) = max(\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{y}_i)$

still a kernel?

Edit2: I also thought of creating a sequence that converges to the max value. For example:
$k_l(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) = \left[\sum_{i=1}^{n!}(\mathbf{x}^T P_i \mathbf{y})^l\right]^{1/l}$
I think that this sequence converges to the max value however, the exponent (1/l) makes each item in the sequence not a kernel.

I could rewrite the sequence as $k_l(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}) =||\mathbf{x}||*||\mathbf{y}|| \left[\sum_{i=1}^{n!}(\cos(\theta_i))^l\right]^{1/l}$ and then try to express the term in the sum as a product of functions of $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$ but so far I haven't managed to achieve anything.

1. Can we prove that this sequence is a valid kernel?
2. Is there any better approach for a sequence that converges to the max value (perhaps some kind of normalization)?